# Issue with Phonegap / iPhone Emulator highlighting element on swipe

Tags: iphone, css, cordova, mobile-safari

Building a phonegap app and I'm having a problem in which swiping up or down on some of the pages that don't have scrollable content highlights the bottom of the element in which you swipe on (in most of my cases my main 'content' div).

I've tried adding the following in hopes this would solve the issue:

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
```

...but sadly this changes nothing. Any ideas on how to stop this random highlighting? Picture below illustrating the problem.

[image: iPhone Emulator Div Issue Picture]

Answer (score 0):

The error ended up being a simple css ruling on my body...

```
height: 100%;
```

Removing this made the error stop appearing...